# Postgres preferring costly ST_Intersects() over cheap index

Tags: sql, postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis

I'm executing a rather simple query on a full planet dump of OSM using Postgres 9.4. What I want to do is fetching all ways which belong to the A8 autobahn in Germany. In a preparation step, I've created multipolygons for all administrative boundary relations and stored them in the table polygons so I can do a more easy spatial intersection test. To allow for a fast query processing, I also created an index for the 'ref' hstore tags:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ways_tags_ref ON planet_20141222.ways USING btree (lower(tags->'ref'));
```

Additionally, I have already obtained the id of the administrative boundary of Germany by a previous query (result id = 51477).

My db schema is the normal API 0.6 schema, the data was imported via the dump approach into Postgres (using the pgsnapshot_schema_0.6*.sql scripts which come with osmosis). VACUUM ANALYZE was also performed for all tables.

The problematic query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wy.id FROM planet_20141222.ways wy, planet_20141222.polygons py
WHERE py.id=51477 AND ST_Intersects(py.geom,wy.linestring) AND ((wy.tags->'highway') is not null) AND (lower(wy.tags->'ref') like lower('A8'));
```

The runtime of this query is terrible because Postgres prefers the costly ST_Intersects() test over the cheap (and highly selective) index on 'ref'. When removing the intersection test, the query returns in some milliseconds.

What can I do so that Postgres first evaluates the parts of the query where an index exists instead of testing each way in the entire planet for an intersection with Germany?

My current solution is to split the SQL query in two separate queries. The first does the index-supported tag tests and the second does the spatial intersection test. I suppose that Postgres can do better, but how?

Edit:

a) the OSM 0.6 import scripts create the following indexes on the ways table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ways_bbox ON ways USING gist (bbox);
CREATE INDEX idx_ways_linestring ON ways USING gist (linestring);
```

b) Additionally, I created another index on polygons:

```
CREATE INDEX polygons_geom_tags on polygons using gist(geom, tags);
```

c) The EXPLAIN ANALYZE output of the query **without** ST_Intersects() looks like this:

```
"Index Scan using ways_tags_ref on ways  (cost=0.57..4767.61 rows=1268 width=467) (actual time=0.064..0.267 rows=60 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (lower((tags -> 'ref'::text)) = 'a8'::text)"
"  Filter: (((tags -> 'highway'::text) IS NOT NULL) AND (lower((tags -> 'ref'::text)) ~~ 'a8'::text))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 5"
"Total runtime: 0.300 ms"
```

The runtime of the query with ST_Intersects() is more than 15 minutes, so I cancelled it.

Comment: I'd suggest creating spatial indexes. It makes ST_Intersects significantly faster. `CREATE INDEX indexname ON tablename USING GIST(columnname);`

Comment: Yup, that will do it. Intersects queries on R-trees are blazingly fast.

Comment: I've edited the posting and provided infos about the r-tree indexes. Unfortunately they are already there.

Comment: In my opinion it would be quite inefficient if Postgres runs spatial intersection tests for all 275 million ways which are currently in OSM. 
From my point of view it makes much more sense to start with the 'ref' b-tree which is highly selective and returns only a few dozen results. The spatial predicate should only be evaluated for those.

Comment: Have you tried reordering the WHERE criteria, so that it evaluates the cheap condition before the expensive conditions?

Comment: How can I do a reordering in Postgres? AFAIK, there are no hints, so the optimizer simply figures out the best query plan based on the available statistics.

Comment: @AlfKortig Please post `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for each query.
@MikeT The order in `WHERE ` doesn't matter

Comment: I've added the query plan for the stripped-down version of the query which finishes in a reasonable time frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try something like this..?

```
WITH wy AS (
  SELECT * FROM planet_20141222.ways 
  WHERE ((tags->'highway') IS NOT null)
  AND (lower(tags->'ref') LIKE lower('A8'))
)
SELECT DISTINCT wy.id 
FROM wy, planet_20141222.polygons py
WHERE py.id=51477 
  AND ST_Intersects(py.geom,wy.linestring);
```

Comment: This sub-query version indeed solves the runtime issue, the result is available in about 1 sec.
Unfortunately the query had to be tuned in such a way that the optimizer doesn't have a choice anymore. Is there a way to let Postgres figure out the best plan and to evaluate the spatial predicate last? Postgres has to have some info about the high cost of ST_Inetrsects().